# Разбить строку на N слов со смещением

Tags: python, алгоритм, текст

Помогите начинающему разбить строку на N слов со смещением на одно слово от прошлого словосочетания.

**Пример для понимания исходный текст:**
Он говорил на том изысканном французском языке......

**результат при N=3:**

```
Он говорил на
говорил на том
на том изысканном
том изысканном французском
```

Подскажите, как данный алгоритм можно реализовать?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Способ 1:

```
string = 'Он говорил на том изысканном французском языке'
N = 3
string_list = string.split()

for i in range(len(string_list)):
    k = string_list[i:i+N]
    if len(k) < N:
        break
    print(*k)
```

Способ 2:

```
for k in zip(*(string_list[x:] for x in range(N))):
    print(' '.join(k))
```

Способ 2, но в одну строку:

```
print(*(' '.join(k) for k in zip(*(string_list[x:] for x in range(N)))), sep='\n')
```

---

Способ 1 с файлом:

```
N = 3
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    string_list = f.read().replace('\n', ' ').split()

file_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    k = string_list[i:i+N]
    if len(k) < N:
        break
    file_out.write(' '.join(k) + '\n')
file_out.close()
```

Способ 2 с файлом:

```
file_out = open('D:\\out.txt', 'w')
for k in zip(*(string_list[x:] for x in range(N))):
    file_out.write(' '.join(k) + '\n')
file_out.close()
```

Comment: А если с файла текст считать и в другой записать?

Comment: @danilko2003 то это уже другой вопрос ;) ответ на который, кстати, сначала можно и самому поискать

Comment: @danilko2003 соглашусь с Jack_oS, лучше создавать новый вопрос или сразу уточнять. Но добавил вариант

Answer (score 3):

```
string = 'Он говорил на том изысканном французском языке'
n = int(input())

for i in range(len(spl)+1-n):
    print(' '.join(spl[i:i+n]))
```

для n=2:

```
>? 2
Он говорил
говорил на
на том
том изысканном
изысканном французском
французском языке
```

для n=5:

```
>? 5
Он говорил на том изысканном
говорил на том изысканном французском
на том изысканном французском языке
```